# Widget opening wrong Activity/MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, widget, android-widget

I have a widget in my app, i added an intent to open a specific activity, but it still opening mainActivity. I checked passing intent from both onRecieve() and onUpdate(), still same.

although it works once the widget is added for the first time, then when you click again on the widget it opens the MainActivity , which is the wrong activity.

```html
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val widgetMgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        widgetMgr.getAppWidgetIds(
            ComponentName(
                context!!,
                PlantWidget::class.java
            )
        )
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        val intent = Intent(context, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

        context.startActivity(intent)


    }
```

Comment: Is the widget/ activity in the back stack? If you hit the back button, does it go to the main activity or to the widget/activity that loaded once?

Comment: it creating a lot of WidgetActivity, in my case SettingsActivtiy, when i try to hit back after some times, it has created a lot of SettingsActivities, i have to hit back a lot

Comment: I'd use navigation component instead of intents. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started
You need to pop the back stack if you don't want the user to go back a lot of times. Then use navigation to send the user to another fragment. If you need to pass more data, use navigation arguments. You can assign/modify then on the nav graph.

Comment: Also for intents, read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters
While you can use intents to change activity, I think they are better used when an activity must return some type of data you need. For example, when the user takes a picture to be uploaded into the app. See implicit vs explicit intents.